# Understanding TCP listening socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I've recently started studying socket implementation in C and I'm confused on how a TCP server is implemented. From what I've understood the server has a listening socket where it accepts connection requests from the clients and then creates a new socket for each client to send and receive data. If that's the case when and where does the TCP handshake happen to start a connection (between the client and the listening socket to create the new one ? )
Could somebody clarify this concept for me ?

Comment: In the client's `connect()` and the server's `accept()`

Comment: You may be interested in [wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wireshark/info) or similar tools. It allows you to see the network traffic.

Comment: It happens automatically in the TCP driver. Once you call `listen()` on the socket, it will perform the handshake on any incoming connections to that port. When you call `accept()`, a new socket is created to allow the server to communicate with it.

Comment: The backlog argument to `listen()` tells it how many connections that haven't been returned in `accept()` calls to buffer, although some implementations don't treat this as a hard limit.

Comment: @Shawn `accept()` doesn't cause the handshake, it just returns the socket that has already been accepted by the kernel.

Comment: @Barmar how is it possible to send data in the third segment of the handshake ? if the listen() performs the handshake then the new socket hasn't been created yet

Comment: The third segment of the handshake is from the client, not the server. So it doesn't matter if `accept()` has been called yet. The client can start using the socket once the second segment has been received.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your help, things are a lot more clear now

Answer (score 0):

The "magic" of TCP handshake here happens in the operating system's kernel.

The POSIX API has socket functions to abstract all that low-level part off your code, so you don't have to worry about TCP handshake, packet manipulation, etc.

From the user-space, all you need to know is that you have a file descriptor to read from and/or write to, the user-space application is not concerned with the handshake or if there's any, unless you're working with kernel-bypass - but in that  case you won't be using the POSIX socket API.

Of course, if you want to know, you'll need to take a look at the kernel code that provides those functions, since it's implementation specific (although these implementations won't be much different from each other).